# Confluent cli to run all services "confluent local services start" in local windows not working

Tags: confluent-platform, confluent-cli

Problem:  Dont get any response when i run “confluent local services start” OR confluent -version
i am able to run zookeeper and kafka by running for eg using below command
bin/zookeeper-server-start etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties

Basically trying to setup confluent in my local windows desktop .
Followed steps from this link
https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-and-wsl-2/

i had followed steps to install wsl 2 in windows and installed ubuntu .
got confluent from
curl -O https://packages.confluent.io/archive/7.3/confluent-7.3.0.tar.gz
unpacked it .

here is few of my laptop setup details

```
tgdesk@LAPTOP-17HPJU8D:~/confluent-7.3.0$ java -version
openjdk version “11.0.20.1” 2023-08-24
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)

tgdesk@LAPTOP-17HPJU8D:~/confluent-7.3.0$ echo $PATH
/home/tgdesk/confluent-7.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program…

tgdesk@LAPTOP-17HPJU8D:~/confluent-7.3.0$ uname -a
Linux LAPTOP-17HPJU8D 4.19.104-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Wed Feb 19 06:37:35 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

tgdesk@LAPTOP-17HPJU8D:~/confluent-7.3.0$ uname -r
4.19.104-microsoft-standard
tgdesk@LAPTOP-17HPJU8D:~/confluent-7.3.0$ confluent local services start
```

No display after this . waited for 10 min.

it looks like individual services like kafka,zookeper starts but not through CLI .

Comment: What if you try latest 7.x release? And OpenJDK 17, the latest supported? And do you have Docker installed, since I think that's a requirement here. Otherwise, Docker Compose works as well. https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.5.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that plugins are disabled for the CLI, as they can cause the Confluent CLI to run very slowly on Windows: https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/plugins.html